# Selectively running layout on new child nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

Question quoted from an email:

> 1. Lets say i have 100s of nodes.
> 2. When i click on Node A (which is already connected to B, C and D), i add few children to it
>      like A1, A2, A3 etc.
> 3. Now, i want to run the layout so that these newly added nodes get positioned correctly.
>
> I was using 
>   cy.$("#A").closedNeighborhood().layout({ name: 'cola' })
>   but i am facing two problems.
>
> 1. The new nodes A1, A2, A3 etc are overlapping with other nodes
> 2. Moreover the position of A and B also getting changed.
>
> I just want to run a layout on the newly added nodes with out the above problems. Please suggest me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

A layout can only be aware of elements that are a part of the layout.  Thus, it can't avoid overlap if you don't specify all the elements you want to consider.

Try locking the nodes you don't want moved and running the layout on the entire graph.